# Why do leeches lose septae due to parasitism?

Tags: zoology, invertebrates

So I found this piece of information in my textbook without a proper explanation, and I can't seem to find the relation between the two.

Comment: Welcome to Bio.SE! What attempts to answer this question have you already taken? We ask that all question posters here attempt to search for an answer to their own question and explicitly indicate what research they've already done, what they learned, and what is still confusing or unknown to them. Our goal is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way :). Please take a moment to edit your post with this additional detail, and it will likely be received more positively by our community. Thanks!

Comment: Please start by editing your post to include the source of your information (in other words, cite your textbook), and please provide a direct quote referencing your piece of information. After dong that, please indicate what other research you've attempted on your own and what you've found out. Thanks.